# Do I have to make a select query to create a relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to create a Blog object which has a relation between User. To create the relationship do I have to select User entity first, then set it to User property of Blog object? In Entity Framework samples suggest to set the User object to ViewState and retrieve it when you need to create the relationship, like a basic cache.

Is this necessary? Is there any other way to do this? (like in linq-to-sql setting the foreign keys only without select.)

Here my code sample;

```
Blog blog = new Blog
            {
                Name = blogName,
                Slogan = slogan,
                User = Entities.Users.First(u => u.Id == userId)
            }

Entities.AddToBlogs(blog);
Entities.SaveChanges();
```

Edit(To give another chance to question): Is there anything unclear or else?

Comment: still no answer? you surprised me guys :) is it unclear or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

We use the following solution to set foreign keys without retreiving the corresponding entity from the context.

```
Blog blog = new Blog            
{                
   Name = blogName,                
   Slogan = slogan,                
   UsersReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("EntityModel.Users", "UserId", userId)            
}

Entities.AddToBlogs(blog);
Entities.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not officially supported at present, [but it may be included in a future version](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2008/10/27/foreign-keys-in-the-conceptual-and-object-models.aspx).

<s>You may be able to hack around it, however. I haven't tried this, but the idea seems conceptually sound:</s>

1. Create a new User, and set the ID appropriately. Attach it to the object context.
2. Tell the object context to forget any changes you have made so far.
3. Now create a new Blog and set the User property to the user you just created.
4. Save changes on the object context.

Obviously, this will fail badly if the User doesn't actually exist in the database.

Seemed like a good idea, but doesn't appear to work. :(

Comment: Unfortunely, that didn't solve the problem. When I did this, the properties of blog is being tried to added and because of constraints an exception is thrown.

Comment: What is the way of doing that? I could not find any method on DataContext to do it. So I've used AcceptAllChanges().

Comment: AcceptAllChanges should do it. Check the Entity state to make sure. As I said, this is speculation on my part; what you're asking isn't officially supported.

Comment: I checked it out. But when I tried to add the blog EntityState of the User is became Added and there is no way to set it manually.

Comment: OK, we can add that idea to the bin of good ideas that didn't work in real life, then. :(